# Получение данных с определенной ячейки в таблице с помощь jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Всем привет!
Есть скрипт:

```js
$(".odpowiedzButton").click(function(){

  var wiersz = $('<tr class="removeOdpowiedz"></tr>');
  var komorka = $('<td colspan="4" class="plabel"></td>');
  var row = $(this).parent().parent();

  $("tr").remove(".removeOdpowiedz");
  wiersz.append(komorka);

  komorka = row.children()[2].text();
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().after(wiersz);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" style="margin: auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Дата</th>
      <th>От</th>
      <th>Заглавие</th>                                 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="3" style="height: 30px;">
      <td>2021-06-02 16:46:47</td>
      <td>Имя</td>
      <td class="cursor-pointer">Красивое заглавие</td>
      <td><button class="odpowiedzButton buttonmoon">Ответить</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Вот в чем проблема:
я пытаюсь в следующей строке, после строки "`<tr data-id="3" style="height: 30px;">...</tr>`"
вывести данные из **второй ячейки** в строке - `<tr data-id="3" style="height: 30px;">...</tr>`
то есть в той же самой строке.
И вот какую ошибку выбивает в консоли браузера:
'**Uncaught TypeError: row.children(...)[2].text is not a function**'
Буду благодарен за любые подсказки, заранее спасибо : )

Comment: `var row = $(this).parent().parent();` замените на `var row = $(this).closest('tr');` и `wiersz = row.children()[2].text();` на `wiersz = row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();`

Comment: Немного не решает проблему, так как полученное значение должно было вставиться как новый элемент <td> со своими классами в элементе <tr> который тоже имеет свои классы

Comment: Объясните что хотите сделать.. по описанию ничего не понятно

Comment: Сейчас у меня имя считывается и просто добавляется в коде как элемент без тегов, а должна появляться строка в той же таблице, пример: <tr class="removeOdpowiedz"><td colspan="4" class="plabel">Имя</td></tr>, а сейчас Имя в коде появляется просто как - "Имя"

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".odpowiedzButton").click(function(){
  //текущий "нажатый" tr
  let row = $(this).closest('tr');
  // создаём новый эл-т tr
  let wiersz = document.createElement('tr');
  // добавляем созданной tr класс
  wiersz.classList.add('removeOdpowiedz');
  // создаём эл-т td
    let komorka = document.createElement('td');
  // для td - добавляем атрибут colspan = 4 
  komorka.setAttribute('colspan', 4);
  // для td - добавляем класс plabel
  komorka.classList.add('plabel');
  // записываем в td текст 2й ячейки нажатого tr
  komorka.innerText = row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
  // добавляем td внутрь tr
  wiersz.append(komorka);
  // добавляем tr в конец body
  row.closest('body').append(wiersz);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" style="margin: auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Дата</th>
      <th>От</th>
      <th>Заглавие</th>                                 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="3" style="height: 30px;">
      <td>2021-06-02 16:46:47</td>
      <td>Имя</td>
      <td class="cursor-pointer">Красивое заглавие</td>
      <td><button class="odpowiedzButton buttonmoon">Ответить</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Можете ли вы создать чат? Я подробнее расскажу о проблеме, если у Вас есть желание

Comment: В общем и целом я делаю почтовый сервис... И когда я нажимаю на строчку с именем и заглавием то под ней должна появляться строчка с содержимым сообщения, и в моем варианте все было хорошо только вот та ошибка которую выдает браузер не дает сервису нормально работать, сейчас по Вашему способу где я заменил две строчки(+ там от меня ошибка и здесь я заменил переменную 'wiersz' на 'komorka' - то есть поменял так: 'komorka = row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();'), и по Вашему способу тоже почти работает, оно создает сейчас эту строчку, только пустую, то есть не вставляет туда полученное значение

Comment: `row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();` - это не нужно ни в какую переменную совать. Вот, у Вашем коде `wiersz = row.children()[2].text();`, wiersz - переменная, которая содержит tr, а Вы её перезаписываете этой строкой. В своём варианте можете сменить `wiersz = row.children()[2].text();` на `wiersz.find('td').text(row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text());`, а строку `wiersz = row.children()[2].text();` вообще удалите

Comment: wiersz = row.children()[2].text() - должно быть так : kolumna = row.children()[2].text(); - уже исправил в коде, проблема в том что wiersz - это изначально не та строка в которой содержатся данные которые я должен получить и с помощью var row = $(this).parent().parent(); я дохожу на два элемента выше и это уже нужна мне строка, именно в ней находятся такие данные как имя и заглавие, потом с помощью komorka = row.children()[2].text(); я присваиваю элементу 'komorka' то есть ячейке, значения второй ячейки с той строки - то есть Имя

Comment: komorka = wiersz.children().text(2); или же можно еще так написать komorka.innerHTML = wiersz.children().text(2); Мне посоветовали сделать данную функцию именно с помощью такого способа, только вот я не могу решить проблему, а именно - 'Uncaught TypeError: row.children(...)[2].text is not a function'

Comment: В сотый раз пишу, что `row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text()` - вот это и есть содержимой 2й TD, а записать её - `wiersz.find('td').text(row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text());`  - это код после `wiersz.append(komorka);`, если хотите до этой строки то `komorka.text(row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text())` ... Вот возьмите и измените свой код в вопросе соответственно с тем, что Вы поняли/исправили/поменяли и напишите как исправите

Comment: $(".odpowiedzButton").click(function(){
     var wiersz = $('<tr class="removeOdpowiedz"></tr>');
     var komorka = $('<td colspan="4" class="plabel"></td>');
     var row = $(this).parent().parent();
     $("tr").remove(".removeOdpowiedz");
      wiersz.append(komorka);
      komorka.text(row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text())
      $(this).parent().parent().after(wiersz);
 }); На данном этапе сделал так как посоветовали, пока что получилось как и  хотел, спасибо!

Comment: Только вот эту строку `komorka.text(row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text())` поместите перед строкой `wiersz.append(komorka);`, а не наоборот, как сейчас

Comment: Потому что выглядит не логично? Сначала добавляем ячейку к строке, а только потом ее заполняем?

Comment: Верно. Не логично.